# Best way to build single javascript file for all of my pages with Typescript

Tags: typescript, requirejs

We are currently using RequireJS with CoffeeScript to generate custom JS files. However, we are not using the "**r.js**" compiler tool to optimize the code with the "define" header. Our current implementation requires that we put the full `define` statement at the top of each coffee file:

```
define('charts/bar', ['charts/base','constants'], (BaseModel, Constants) ->
  class BarChart extends BaseModel
    ...
```

We are looking to move to TypeScript so we can make use of refactoring and all the other goodness that comes with it. The problem that we are running into is that we have not been able to figure out how to compile all of our TypeScript files into a single file.

For example, assume the following files:

- charts/

  - bar.ts
  - line.ts
  - base.ts
- users/

  - profile.ts
  - security.ts
  - friends.ts
- data/

  - geo.ts
  - population.ts
  - voting.ts

With all of these files, we want to put them into a single file called `utils.js` and reuse this js file across multiple pages. One page might only use the **users/security** class, while the next page might use the **data/geo** class along with some of the various **chart** classes.

How can we construct this using requirejs?

**Note:** One thing to keep in mind is that we don't have a single entry point to this class. It's purpose is solely to be used for helper classes and base implementations that we can extend in other classes.

Comment: Bundling is not a typescript concern. Typescript will generate the appropriate JS files for you (including the define blocks) but stitching them together should be the work of your bundler (browserify/uglify/r.js/etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can we construct this using requirejs?

Use `import/require` and compile with option `--module amd`.

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html

PS: highly recommend moving to commonjs. But that is opinionated

Comment: Thanks for the information. We already had this, but were missing two switches. We resorted to actually calling the compiler twice: "outDir" (write all files to this directory) and "out" (write all output to one file) are the two switches. As for using commonjs, we can't because we aren't using nodejs. Thanks again!